# How to access custom session attribute in template

Tags: django

I fail to access a value that I stored in the session:

## views.py

```
...
    request.session['content_lang_code'] = request.GET.get('lang')
```

## base.html template

```
</body>
<p>Hello {{ request.user.username }} your selected content language is:
    session.content_language_code {{ session.content_language_code }} <br>
    request.session.content_language_code {{ request.session.content_language_code }}
</p>
```

While the username is rendered, content_language_code is not. The debugger shows that content_language_code is in session._session. I tried session.get('content_language_code') as well, but that did no work either.

What is the correct way to retrieve a session attribute from within a template?

(debug screen shot at http://lcrfiles.hoerbe.at/stuff/screenshot2013-03-29.png)

Answer (score 0):

You put it in the session with the key `content_lang_code` but are trying to access it with a different key `content_language_code`. If you change `{{ request.session.content_language_code }}` to `{{ request.session.content_lang_code }}` it should work.

Comment: thank you, that worked. For my curiosity: I was distracted from the obvious because the attribute is stored in session._session, not in session. What is the reason for this?

Comment: That's just where it stores the values internally. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase The `__getitem__` method (called when you do `session['key']` accesses `_session` to retrieve the value you ask for.